# How can i group a large amount of POIs in Mapquest for Actionscript?

Tags: flash, actionscript, mapquest

I have a large amount of POIs at the same spot (e.g. the same district). If i zoom out the map i want to group these nearby POIs to one big Spot so that the map doesn't get filled up with pois.

For example: http://developer.mapquest.com/web/documentation/sdk/flash/v7.0/poi#poidecluttering

But instead of decluttering them i want to group them into 1 bigger spot.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [the Super POI functionality](http://developer.mapquest.com/content/as/v/mq/samples/samplesexplorer/index.html#samplegroup=PoisAndInfoWindows&sample=SuperPoiSample&hide=true).  This example is included in the [Flash Samples Explorer](http://developer.mapquest.com/content/as/v/mq/samples/samplesexplorer/index.html#) application that can be found on the [MapQuest Developer Network](http://developer.mapquest.com).

Also, I've found the [forums](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/info/forums) to be helpful, too, so just wanted to note that it is another resource that you can use when you have questions.

Comment: Thanks for your replay but this wasn't exactly what i'm looking for. I thought there may be an automatic mechanism which groups nearby POI so that the map does not gets crowded. For example: [link](https://market.android.com/details?id=at.oeamtc.android). If you download the app, go to "Tanken" (refill gas) and pan to Austria you will find gas stations as POIs on a map. If you zoom out they turn into big points with numbers in them.